# How to create UI like BottomSheet in iPhone for iPad devices

Tags: ipad, swiftui, swift5, bottom-sheet, ios16

[image][image]I'm new to SwiftUI. I want to create a UI for iPad devices similar to BottomSheet in iPhone devices. How can we create UI like BottomSheet for iPad.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            showingSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            Text("This is my app")
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
    }
}
```

I have added screenshots of iPad and iPhone devices for your reference .Is there any other way to achieve similar ui for iPad.Thanks in advance.

Comment: iPads ignore `. presentationDetents` and always place a sheet like you have shown in your first image. If you want a full screen sheet like `.large` on iPhone you can substitute a `.fullScreenCover`. If, however, you want detents like iPhone, you will have to roll your own view for it.

Comment: Is there any workaround to get the presentationDetents working for iPad.

Comment: I have created the bottom sheet like UI for iPad  using GeometryReader and it is working fine. But I'm not able to drag the sheet upward  from mid height to max height like .presentationDetents[.medium, .large].

Comment: Ask a new question and provide that code. see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).